# Offline tool for validating a json file with respect to a json schema

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, json

I'm looking for a desktop application that lets you check whether a json file satisfies a certain json schema. I've found some web applications that do the job, though I have to use the tool on Windows without being connected to the Internet. It would be nice if the tool has a UI that allows me to edit the json file and the schema. It would also be nice if the tool tells me exactly what's wrong with a given json file that violates the schema. However, I can live without these two features.

I'm aware to the fact that [JsonBuddy](http://www.json-buddy.com/) can validate jsons with respect to a schema but I prefer a freeware if one exists. Unfortunately, I couldn't have found one. Is there such a tool?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Tom, Windows 7

Comment: JSONBuddy is currently available at 10$ from [json-buddy.com](http://json-buddy.com) Not really free but almost ;)

Comment: It has gone up to $29 now :-(    [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69065/gratis-windows-alternative-to-jsonbuddy) is my question asking for a gratis alternative

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio and other JetBrains IDEs have support for JSON schema validation.

For Android Studio:

- gratis
- available on Windows
- > has a UI that allows me to edit the json file and the schema

  Yes, but the schema has to be opened manually
- > tool tells me exactly what's wrong with a given json file that violates the schema:

  Visualizes the problems in the text editor component, offers quick fixes and show the problems listed in the Problems component

When a JSON file is opened, there's a segment in status bar that shows the status of the JSON schema validation. By default, there's no schema configured to validate against and it says *No JSON schema*. Clicking on it brings up the configuration to specify the schema to validate against.

Answer (score 0):

If you would be fine with JSON Schema draft 7, then http://tomeko.net/software/JSONedit/ ("Tools" menu) has it since 2023.02.

It is using https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons for this functionality and this library can be easily used to create more customized tools.